# Show that the product of the Jacobian and the inverse Jacobian is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I have seen the following fact in a textbook, but am having trouble proving it. If the Jacobian ("stretch factor" for change-of-variables) is given by

$\left | \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \right | =  \begin{vmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&  \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\\ 
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}&   \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}$, with $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$,

then

$\left | \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \right | \left | \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)} \right | = 1$.

I am attempting to show this is true by multiplying the matrices and then taking the determinant of the product, but I do not understand how the product becomes equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0\\ 
  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit of caution, if the representation above is for the Jacobian matrix then i think you should use $[]$ brackets and if you are computing the determinant of the Jacobian matrix then $|.|$ symbol is used, also $\left | \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \right | \left | \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)} \right | = 1$, doesnot make sense if you are thinking of matrices as the LHS is the product of matrices which again must be a matrix but the RHS is a number, eeven dimesnion won't agree?. I think you are considering determinant of the Jacobain matrix??

Comment: You need the condition that the Jacobian doesn’t vanish.

Answer (score 9):

We have $$x = x(u,v)  \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ y = y(u,v)$$
then the **chain rule for functions of several variables** states that
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$ But $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1$$
I'll use these facts later on. For now,

> I believe we are trying to prove $$ \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = I$$ where $$I = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
>   We'll also prove $$\Bigg \lvert \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\Bigg \rvert = 1$$

So we begin:

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{vmatrix}$$

$$ = \det \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix} \Bigg ) \det \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \Bigg )$$

$$ = \det \Bigg ( \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \Bigg )$$

by the identity $$\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$$

so $$ \det \Bigg ( \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \Bigg )$$

$$ = \det \Bigg ( \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \Bigg )$$

$$ = \det \Bigg ( \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\end{bmatrix} \Bigg )$$

$$ = \det \Bigg ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} & 1\end{bmatrix} \Bigg ) $$
by the chain rule for functions of several variables, using what we found above.

Now, since $x$ is not a function of $y$, and $y$ is not a function of $x$, we have $$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$$

so $$ \det \Bigg ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} & 1\end{bmatrix} \Bigg ) = \det \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Bigg ) = \det(I)$$

so we've proven that $$ \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = I $$

Now, $$ \det(I) = \det \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Bigg ) = 1 $$

so we've also proven that $$ \Bigg \lvert \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\Bigg \rvert = 1 $$ as required

Comment: This is interesting, because the chain rule is not correct (or not rigorous/standard), but because you ended up proving the result, it makes me think that your chain rule has some "symbolic intuition" behind it. What we have is a multivariable, vector-valued function, $a: (u,v) \mapsto (x,y)$ (functions of the form $a: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$). That is, we have a function $f: (u,v) \mapsto x$ and a $g: (u,v) \mapsto y$. You assumed that $a$ has an inverse function $a^{-1}: (x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$. In other words, you assumed there are functions $h: (x,y) \mapsto u$ and $I:(x,y) \mapsto v$

Comment: Then you formed the composition $f(h(x,y), I(x,y))$, which since $h,I$ are inverse functions, $f(h(x,y), I(x,y)) = x$. Therefore taking partial derivatives with respect to $x$ of this composition function, we get $$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(h(x,y), I(x,y)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = 1$$

Comment: (it's composition functions which the chain rule applies to)

Comment: hmmm good point indeed, haha that's the only way I could think to solve the problem, but yeah thanks for the comment

Comment: even for my own interest I'm wondering now if there's a better way to prove the OP question

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculation straight forward.

$$
\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = 
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x_u & x_v \\
    y_u & y_v \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = 
    \begin{vmatrix}
    u_x & u_y \\
    v_x & v_y \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
So, we want to prove is,
$$
\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = x_uy_vu_xv_y + xvy_uu_yv_x - x_uy_vu_yv_x - x_vy_uu_xv_y = 1
$$
Since $x = x(u, v)$, $y = y(u, v)$,
Thus,
$$dx = x_udu + x_vdv$$
$$dy = y_udu + y_vdv$$
By chain rule,
$$\frac{dx}{dx} = x_uu_x + x_vv_x = 1 \qquad (1)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = x_uu_y + x_vv_y = 0 \qquad (2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dy} = y_uu_y + y_vv_y = 1 \qquad (3)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y_uu_x + y_vv_x = 0 \qquad (4)$$
Then, showing $$(1) \times (3) - (2) \times (4) = \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = x_uy_vu_xv_y + xvy_uu_yv_x - x_uy_vu_yv_x - x_vy_uu_xv_y = 1$$
Q.E.D

Comment: BTW, [Patrick Jankowski's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2956227/759556) is almost correct except for the chain rule. Using det(A)det(B) = det(AB) and try to prove AB = I is really good and fast!!!