# How to change coordinates and variables when doing double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let D be the bounded region in the first quadrant of $R^2$ bounded by curves
$x^2 + 16y^2 = 16, x^2 + 16y^2 = 1, x = y$ and the positive y−axis.
Describe $D$ in the $(u, v)$−plane when $u = x^2 + 16y^2$ and $v =\frac yx,$ and calculate the integral $$\iint_{D} \frac{y}{x} dA$$

So in order to solve the integral I used the new coordinates $1\leq u \leq 16$ and $1\leq v \leq \infty$. Afterwards I calculated the the determinant of the jacobian and got $$ |\det J| = 1+32\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 = 2 + 32v^2$$
Then I did:
$$\iint_{D} v (2 + 32v^2) dudv$$
But I got the wrong answer and instead in the answers they divided the determinant of jacobian.
$$\iint_{D} \frac{v}{(2 + 32v^2)} dudv$$

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Can you break down your calculation of that determinant?

Comment: Also, edit your post to include a *careful* statement of the change of variables formula.

Comment: Remember, if you have the change of variables: $x=x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$, and your integrand is $f(x,y),$ then the change of variables states the transformed integrand is $f(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \left |\det \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \right|.$ There is also a rule involving the Jacobian determinant, which is extremely useful: $\left |\det \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \right|= (\left |\det \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)} \right|)^{-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the change of variables $u=x^2+16y^2$ and $v=y/x$, in your exercise you should consider the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the transformation $\Phi$ from $(u,v)$ to $(x,y)$:
$$|\det(J_{\Phi}(u,v))|=\Big|\det\Big(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\Big)\Big|=\begin{vmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&  \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\ 
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}&   \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Instead you computed the determinant of the Jacobian of the inverse transformation $\Phi^{-1}$:
$$|\det(J_{\Phi^{-1}}(x,y))|=\Big|\det\Big(\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\Big)\Big|=\begin{vmatrix}
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\ 
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&   \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
2x&  32y\\ 
  -y/x^2&   1/x
\end{vmatrix}=2+32y^2/x^2$$
which is, due to the chain rule, the reciprocal of $|\det(J_{\Phi}(u,v))|$ (see also [Show that the product of the Jacobian and the inverse Jacobian is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956102/show-that-the-product-of-the-jacobian-and-the-inverse-jacobian-is-1) ). Hence,
$$\iint_D\frac{y}{x} dxdy =\iint_{\Phi^{-1}(D)}\frac{y/x}{2+32y^2/x^2} dudv 
=\int_{1}^{16}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{v}{2+32v^2} dv\right)du.$$